# Html.Password doesn't work as expected Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have this view :

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Giriş</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("TCKimlikNo","TC Kimlik No :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("TCKimlikNo", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Sifre", "Şifre :", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Password("Sifre", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it looks like this :

[image]

I want to make Sifre look like the textbox above. And I want that textbox to be empty. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the [`(string name, Object value)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538031(v=vs.111).aspx), so your anonymous object's `ToString()` goes into the textbox as the value.

Apparently you wanted to call the [`(string name, Object value, Object htmlAttributes)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569122(v=vs.111).aspx):

```
@Html.Password("Sifre", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```